# Batch File not working for the given input

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

Following is the batch file that I have created, for any input its only showing is "NO INPUT PROVIDED" string, I tried searching on google and tried many things but non solved my problem.

```
@echo off
ECHO Please provide input... Valid input is :: Y/y (For changing path) or N/n (For not changing the path).

SETLOCAL
SET /p change=

if  "%~1" equ "" GOTO ERROREND

if /I "%change%" equ "Y" GOTO YES

if /I "%change%" equ "N" GOTO NO

:YES
    ECHO Y SELECTED.
    GOTO SUCCESS

:NO
    ECHO N SELECTED.
    GOTO SUCCESS
:ERROREND
    ECHO Input not recognized.
    GOTO FAILURE

:SUCCESS 
    ECHO Task completed succcess fully.
    pause

:FAILURE
    ECHO NO INPUT PROVIDED.
    pause
```

Help needed. Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: And the reason for `"%~1"` is ... ?

Comment: The reason was to identify if no input is been provided then send it to error label.

Comment: `SET /p change=` -> The input goes to `change` variable, not first argument to batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if  "%~1" equ "" GOTO ERROREND
```

means 'if the first parameter to the batchfile is empty', so if you were to run this batch from the prompt as

```
yourbatchname something
```

then `something` is the first parameter.

You probably menat to use "%change%", not `"%~1".

Note: `if not defined change` is probably a better test.

Note: Simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when prompted by a `set /p` does **not** set the variable to *empty*. It leaves the value unchanged. Best to use

```
set "var="
set /p var=....
```

Note: batch simply charges on, instruction by instruction. It has no concept of 'end-of-procedure'. Consequently, if your entry is neither `Y` nor `N` (once you've got the `%~1` issue resolved) batch will simply continue execution past the `if` statements to the next - the `ECHO Y SELECTED.`